# crystal reports are blank sometimes

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I have an MS Access data base with more than 1000 rows in some tables.

**Here is my code.**

on a button click event: It is creating the folder and putting all `pdfs` in it. Only the pdf beyond number 7 are blank **(do not show data, but shows design text objects)**.and the details section , which is for main table1 adapter is displaying only first row of data set.means its not doing what it is supposed to do.The data set has data is it( which shows preview data).

I also verified the data base many times. tested connection too.So i don't sure what's going wrong. The crystal report version is the one that comes inclusive with visual studio 2008.

Please help.

Moral boosting comments are most welcome, as i have been stuck on this for 3 days. :(

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim locnoreq As String
Dim secreq As Integer
Dim zonereq = pszone.Text
Dim ps As String

Dim ds As New DataSet1()
Dim foldername As String
foldername = zonereq.Substring(0, 2)
'MsgBox(foldername)
Dim ExportFolder As String = Application.StartupPath + "\" + foldername
If Not IO.Directory.Exists(ExportFolder) Then
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(ExportFolder)
End If
'Dim locnoreq = psloc.SelectedValue
'Dim xx = psloc.SelectedIndex + 1
For i = 0 To psloc.Items.Count - 1
    Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1()
    psloc.SelectedIndex = i
    filldata() 'fills sector no(lblsector) label
    filldata1() 'modifies textbox 18 ps value
    'MsgBox(lblsector.Text)
    locnoreq = psloc.Text
    secreq = CType(lblsector.Text(), Integer)
    ps = TextBox18.Text

    'MsgBox(zonereq & "zonereq pszone")
    'MsgBox(secreq & "secreq lblsector")
    'MsgBox(locnoreq & "psloc")
    'MsgBox(ps & "textbox18")
    Dim main_adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("select Sectt_No,AC_No,PS_No,PS_Name,PA_Assigned,PS_Location,M,F,Total,Nature,PP1,CRPF,Bus_No from MainTable where AC_No='" & zonereq & "'and PS_Location='" & locnoreq & "'", con1)
    main_adapter.Fill(ds, "MainTable")
    main_adapter.Dispose()
    Dim zones_adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("select Magistrate,Magistrate_No,ZonalOfficer,ZonalOfficer_No from Zones where AC_No='" & zonereq & "'", con1)
    zones_adapter.Fill(ds, "Zones")
    zones_adapter.Dispose()

    Dim location_adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("select CPMF,CPMF_No,Lady_Worker,Police_Station,Sections from Location where AC_No='" & zonereq & "' and PS_Location='" & locnoreq & "'", con1)
    location_adapter.Fill(ds, "Location")
    location_adapter.Dispose()
    Dim ps_adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("select Zonal_SP,Zonal_SP_No,SDPO,SDPO_No,SHO,SHO_No from pstable where Police_Station='" & ps & "'", con1)
    ps_adapter.Fill(ds, "pstable")
    ps_adapter.Dispose()
    Dim sectors_adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("select Sectt_Mag,Sectt_Mag_No,Sectt_Off,Sectt_Off_No from sectors where AC_No='" & zonereq & "' and Sectt_No=" & secreq & "", con1)
    sectors_adapter.Fill(ds, "sectors")
    sectors_adapter.Dispose()
    Dim main1_adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("select PS_No,PS_Name,PA_Assigned,M,F,Total,PP1,Bus_No from MainTable where AC_No='" & zonereq & "'and PS_Location='" & locnoreq & "'order by ID asc", con1)
    main1_adapter.Fill(ds, "MainTable1")
    main1_adapter.Dispose()
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
    Dim frm2 As New Form2
    frm2.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt

    'rpt.ExportOptions.DestinationOptions = Application.StartupPath + "\" + foldername + "\" + i + 1 + ".pdf"
    'rpt.ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
    'rpt.ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat

    ''Export the report
    'rpt.Export()
    rpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Application.StartupPath & "\" & foldername & "\" & i + 1 & ".pdf")
    frm2.CrystalReportViewer1.Dispose()
    frm2.Close()
    rpt.Refresh()
    rpt.Close()
    rpt.Dispose()

    ds.Clear()
    clear()

Next
MsgBox("Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED!!!
The problem was with  the links in my data set. I deleted some and kept the others( some kind of brute force thing :D), and it worked fine.Though i don't know how.